# What is the difference in rsUnpackColor8888() from float4 convert_float4(char4 v) - Android/Renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I came across this site with RenderScript examples, here a sample:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/java/tests/ImageProcessing2/src/com/android/rs/image/greyscale.rs?autodive=0%2F

Now they use `rsUnpackColor8888` to unpack a `char` to an array of 4 floats.
Why dont use `convert_float4(char4 v);` from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_convert.html ?

What is the difference?

The first one says: "Unpacks a uchar4 color to float4. The resulting floats will be between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive.". So does the second one right?

Comment: I'm rather sure convert_float4 does simply _float result = (float) charvalue_ per element and does not limit it to [0, 1] but [0, 255] instead.

Comment: @harism why would somebody call **convert_float4(on a uchar4)** ? You can still use mathematical notations, like addition etc etc on a **uchar** right? It still takes values 0-255

Comment: What if somebody needed more precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsUnpackColor8888()` normalizes values color components to [0, 1] range. `convert_float4()` does no such thing, so you will get floats in [0, 255] range. When converting the other way around, `convert_uchar4()` rounds down and clamps the output to [0, 255] (i.e. it correctly handles values <0 and >255).

Comment: Why is it in float anyway? Isn't it better and easier to use int ? And how do you use the float?

Comment: Are you asking why the original example used a float?

Comment: It's more of a general question, but if you want to use the example for explaining it, it's also good. :)

Comment: Actually it was easier to use floats, because multiplication factors in the example are fractions. One could naturally implement it with integer numbers, but it would require more operations and be less clear. As for relative performance, see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015660/renderscript-optimizing-data-types-to-increase-speed/32016753#32016753

Comment: How come floats are easier? Isn't it easier read it this way (and convert to hexadecimal color value) ? And also for the CPU/GPU to handle integers instead of floats (as floats are more complex) ? The link actually says that float are worse on performance. Also, how would you use integers instead? I'm learning RS currently, so I don't know much about it.